# почему окно моментально закрывается? (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame



scr = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
scr.fill('green')

pygame.init()

f1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

text = f1.render(
    'there is nothing', True, (255, 215, 0)
)

scr.blit(text, (150, 300))

rect = pygame.Rect(150, 50, 200, 80)
pygame.draw.rect(scr, 'red', rect=rect)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно создать бесконечный цикл чтоб окно не закрывалось

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

scr = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
scr.fill('green')

f1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

text = f1.render(
    'there is nothing', True, (255, 215, 0)
)

scr.blit(text, (150, 300))

rect = pygame.Rect(150, 50, 200, 80)
pygame.draw.rect(scr, 'red', rect=rect)

# основной цикл событий
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Код дошёл до конца и просто закрылся. Надо добавить бесконечный цикл в конец:

```
running = True
while running:
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```